# Service to Support Data Lake Set Up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-data-lake, alibaba-cloud, data-lake

I have to test and compare the available solutions to create a Data Lake.

Is there any other service that makes it easy to set up a secure data lake besides AWS Lake Formation?

I know that I can create an account on Azure and Google Cloud Platform, but I wonder if they have any "package" with the solutions I need, or service to help me set up the data lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Data Lake](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/data-lake/) includes all the capabilities required to make it easy for developers, data scientists, and analysts to store data of any size, shape, and speed, and do all types of processing and analytics across platforms and languages.

To set up the data lake solution, you could use the powerful solutions as below.

- [**HDInsight**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/
- [**Data Lake Analytics**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-analytics/) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/
- [**Azure Data Lake Storage**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/data-lake-storage/) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction